# zipping multiple files with matching pattern in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to compress a list of files generated by previous processor. The names are random with start & end as repetitive.

```
Ex: 
part-00000-1dfde626-2a4f-4bc2-aa43-eaf3c940b2a8-c000.csv
part-00000-547c93da-088e-46c4-a478-a41aabfef9ea-c000.csv
```

I'm trying to zip all the files in one single file using `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor. Following are my command & its arguments: It doesn't work.

```
command: /bin/zip
Argument: finalCompressedFile.zip;part.*csv
```

The regex `part.*csv` does match with all the file patterns generated. But the `*` is (what I suspect) is getting passed to bash shell as literal. If I give a single full file name, it does the job but then I won't be compressing all the files.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Can you not use `ListFile` -> `FetchFile` -> `MergeContent` approach? That lets you provide filename filter and `MergeContent` supports zip format.

Comment: `ListFile` doesn't takes input; I need to provide input to whatever process/processor does the job.

Comment: as i know `zip` command does not accept regex as a parameter. it accepts the usual shell file matcher where `.` is just a dot and `*` matches any length of any chars.  i guess matcher should be like this: `part*.csv`

Comment: Not sure on this but I tested zip command exactly like mentioned above on shell & it compressed all files. When I pass the same from NiFi, it doesn't work.

On the other note, `part*.csv` isn't a valid regex for the file name mentioned in the query. The valid regex is `part.*csv`.

Comment: did you set `ignore input stream`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I remember I've seen something related but can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Yes, I tried ignoring STDIN as well, doesn't work.